# callback in $http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.url})

Tags: http, angularjs, get

```
$scope.fetchQA = function() {

    $scope.url = 'js/jsons/QA.json';

    $http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.url}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.QA = data;
    });
  }

  $scope.fetchQA();

  function x(){
    alert(QA);
  }
```

How do i use `function x` as a callback for $http.get? or is there any other way to ensure that x() will get executed only after reception of data in `fetchQA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the callback right after your logic:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.url}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.QA = data;
    x();
});
```

Comment: when u put it like that! I wonder why didn't i think of it! :)

Comment: @SangramSingh -- Happens all the time, especially when you start thinking async in the beginning. :D